# Run c program with many inputs and save to file?

Tags: c, matlab, input

I want to run my C program in the command line( which I know), but i want to execute it many time for a range of value, lets say n= 100 to 2000 in steps of 10? ie 100,110 etc...till 2000

Also I want to modify my program so that I can manipulate the results in matlab, I want to plot the values I get. I have 3 outputs, and I want each of them stored in one columns for each run, how could I do that?

How to save them excel or in a file?

EDIT :

I have done the following to run the program several times
for(( n=100;n<=2000;n+=100)); do ./ass_1 n; done
but it take the input for each iteration as n=0, why?

Comment: You can output your values as a csv (comma separated values) file and then plot them in excel.

Answer (score 2):

a bash loop will do the job for many time run

```
#!/bin/bash 
for (( c=100; c<=2000; c+=100 )) 
do 
    echo "Hello $" 
done
```

for your output just write it to a file

```
file = fopen(filename, "w");
for or while loop on your data
    fprintf(file, "%d;%d;%d\n", val1, val2, val3);
fclose(file);
```